# Difference between apt-get -d install & apt-get download

Tags: apt

**Apt** (Advanced Packaging Tool) has option to download only package by `apt-get -d install [pkg-name]`.
I have also find `apt-get download [pkg-name]` to download packages.

Then what is the difference between `--download-only` (`apt-get -d install`)and `download` (`apt-get download`)?

**And When should I use between them**?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I could list following:

1. Try both without sudo, `apt-get download` will pass and `apt-get -d install` will fail **(root required)**
2. By default `apt-get -d install` will save .deb in `/var/cache/apt/archives` and `apt-get download` in current directory
3. `apt-get download` is newer, you wouldn't even find it in the old versions.

From [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/apt-get.8.html):

> `download` download will download the given binary package into the current directory.
>
> `-d`, `--download-only` Download only; package files are only retrieved, not unpacked or installed. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Download-Only.

Comment: Have a look at `man apt-get`.

Answer (score 11):

The `--download-only` switch needs to be accompanied by another command, be it `install`, `upgrade` or whatever command would require to download package. If you don't need to download packages, is plain as day that it wouldn't download anything. `--download-only` restricts apt actions to just downloading the packages that **it needs into the cache directory, nothing more**. If your operation would end into downloading dependencies it will download them for you.

Since it needs a command like `install` or `upgrade` it normally would require `sudo` or root permissions, since the default directory used to download the packages is owned by root.

The `download` command is standalone, it reads the package list and download only the package specified, **it doesn't download dependencies nor other packages. It doesn't require root permissions** if you can write your current directory, this wouldn't store the files in the package cache directory.

Comment: something doesn't make sense here. `install --download-only` has the word "install" in it, but does NOT install actually?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `man` command :)

`apt-get download` will download the package, but not its dependencies, to the *current* directory.

`apt-get -d install` will download the given package and all missing dependencies to the system packages directory (`/var/cache/apt/archives`).

Use the first if you want to download a .deb to then tinker with it (uncompress it, poke at it with `dpkg`, whatever).

Use the second if you want to "pre-download" a set of packages for later installation.