# Can I download updates, but not install them with apt-get

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I've got a few hundred ubuntu machines that I need to update, and I'd like to space it over a week and then once they're all updated, space patching over another week.

Is there a way to just download updates so they're ready a week before actually doing the upgrade with apt-get?

Comment: look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/463380/difference-between-apt-get-d-install-apt-get-download

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to its man page, `apt-get upgrade --download-only` will only retrieve packages; it will not unpack them or install them.

Still according to the man page, `apt-get upgrade --no-download --ignore-missing` will force APT to use only the .debs it has already downloaded.