# How can I use apt install on a computer with no network connection (from USB)?

Tags: apt, software-installation, usb

I need to install network tools on a computer which has no network connection. It has working USB ports. Can I do this with apt? If so, how do I get network packages onto a USB stick?

Answer (score 1):

You could download those deb files with

```
sudo apt download pkgname
```

as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463380/difference-between-apt-get-d-install-apt-get-download).

Do not be irritated by the following warning

> Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file

The files will be in the directory where you issued the command

Copy the debs unto you stick. On the second machine you may either use gdebi (the graphical installer) or `dpkg`to install the packages. Make sure you have all the dependent packages installed as well...

Answer (score -1):

the /etc/apt/sources.list support file:// protocol

Comment: This answer isn't detailed enough to be useful.